# From confusion matrix to ROC graph

Tags: object-recognition, roc, confusion-matrix

i recently implemented a Bag of Words categorization algorithm based on the one described in [this paper](http://217.109.185.161/layout/set/print/content/download/20785/148346/file/2004_010.pdf).

All works well, but i'd like to measure accuracies of the classifiers using ROC curves or, perhaps, precision-recall graphs.

I can easily get the confusion matrix for each of the classifiers but i don't know what parameter i should change to get more points and actually plot the curves.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's necessary for the classifier's output to be continuous values rather than discrete values to draw a ROC curve. If the predicted labels are continuous values, then you could set a threshold to calculate points in the ROC curve. If predicted labels are in two classes (discrete values), then you will only get one point in the ROC curve.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic